# jQuery/Javascript the comparison operators "===" and "=="

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparison, operators

in dreamweaver cc 2015, when i am using the comparison operators in jquery/javascript programming like:

```
 if(x == "")
```

DW shows an error that Expected **===** and instead saw **==**. My question is that what is the difference between === and == ?. 
As i know in other languages like C# etc the === operator means that the comparison will check the Data Type of the value as well as the value. In javascript or jquery is there any problem if i use the == instead of === ? or still the result will be the same in jquery / javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, `===` do not try to coerce the type of the variables you are testing, while `==` will do its best to 'typecast' those variables if needed to compare them.

For instance `1 == '1'` returns `true`, while `1 === '1'` returns `false` since you are comparing a number to a string.

Lastly, jQuery and pure javascript both uses the same `===` and `==` operators. Hence, there will not be any difference between the two.

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) is pretty good too.

Answer (score 2):

The `==` operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions. The `===` operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type `===` will simply return false. Both are equally quick.
For more you can check this answer in stack oveflow
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight difference between == and === operators. If you are using == that means you are comparing just values for example (5=='5') will return you true whereas first operand is integer and the second operand is string.Now considering the same example with === i.e (5==='5') will return you false because the '===' operator will check the value as well as type conversion and in this case integer cannot be equal to the string. Hope this helps you.